# web middleware laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-5

I'm trying to use the middleware web, but when I put my route inside it, my project stop working and shows this error

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

When I remove and use my route outside the middleware web, works again. What could be? (Sorry for my english, it is not my native language).

This works:

```
Route::get('/contact', 'TicketsController@create');
Route::post('/contact', 'TicketsController@store');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

});
```

This not works:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/contact', 'TicketsController@create');
    Route::post('/contact', 'TicketsController@store');
});
```

Comment: try to remove brackets from `web` and try : `['middleware' => 'web']`.

Comment: isn't work ... but i found how to solve it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to solve this

1. you must generate a key with **php artisan key:generate**
2. In **config/app.php** place generate key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

I set true debug property in config/app.php ('debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true) ) and i see how to fix that

Comment: Just as a note, you can place your key in .env (Artisan should do this automatically) along with setting whether debug should be enabled there, too.